# Is Quartz scheduler persistent

Tags: java, scheduling

Could I get some insight on whether Quartz scheduler is persistent like EJB Timers (it is an alternative of EJB Timer).
Will it sustain server shutdown and crashes?

Comment: It is if you configure it to be. Have you looked at the docs? http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Quartz supports different **JobStores** and **Misfires** to sustain server shutdown and crashes.

See: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09